# ffmpeg works at command line but I got this error when I use it in nodejs app:

Tags: node.js, npm, ffmpeg, node-modules, yarnpkg

This is the code:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import googleTTS from 'google-tts-api';
import https from 'https';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

async function convertTextToVoice(text, fileName) {
  const outputFile = `./audios/${fileName}.mp3`;

  const words = text.split(' ');
  const chunks = [];
  let chunk = '';

  for (const word of words) {
    if (chunk.length + word.length < 200) {
      chunk += ' ' + word;
    } else {
      chunks.push(chunk.trim());
      chunk = word;
    }
  }

  chunks.push(chunk.trim());

  for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    const chunkFile = `./audios/${fileName}-chunk${i}.mp3`;
    const url = await googleTTS.getAudioUrl(chunks[i], {
      lang: 'ar',
      slow: false,
      host: 'https://translate.google.com',
    });


    try {
      const file = await fs.createWriteStream(chunkFile);
      https.get(url, response => {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', () => {
          file.close();
          console.log(`Chunk ${i} created successfully`);
        });
      }).on('error', error => {
        console.error(`Error downloading chunk ${i}: ${error}`);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  const chunkFiles = chunks.map((chunk, i) => `./audios/${fileName}-chunk${i}.mp3`);

  // Use ffmpeg to merge the audio files
  const concatCommand = `ffmpeg -i "concat:${chunkFiles.join('|')}" -acodec copy ${outputFile}`;
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      exec(concatCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(`Error executing ffmpeg command: ${error}`);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log(`Audio file ${outputFile} created successfully`);
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });

    for (const chunkFile of chunkFiles) {
      await fs.promises.unlink(chunkFile);
      console.log(`${chunkFile} deleted successfully`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

This is the Error:
./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3
ffmpeg -i "concat:./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3" -acodec copy ./audios/تجربة.mp3
Error executing ffmpeg command: Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i "concat:./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3" -acodec copy ./audios/تجربة.mp3
ffmpeg version 2023-02-04-git-bdc76f467f-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      57. 44.100 / 57. 44.100
libavcodec     59. 63.100 / 59. 63.100
libavformat    59. 38.100 / 59. 38.100
libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
libavfilter     8. 56.100 /  8. 56.100
libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
[mp3 @ 00000177df48a1c0] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 00000177df48a1c0] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026.
concat:./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3: Invalid argument

Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i "concat:./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3" -acodec copy ./audios/تجربة.mp3
ffmpeg version 2023-02-04-git-bdc76f467f-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      57. 44.100 / 57. 44.100
libavcodec     59. 63.100 / 59. 63.100
libavformat    59. 38.100 / 59. 38.100
libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
libavfilter     8. 56.100 /  8. 56.100
libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
[mp3 @ 00000177df48a1c0] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 00000177df48a1c0] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026.
concat:./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3: Invalid argument

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
```

code: 1,
killed: false,
signal: null,
cmd: 'ffmpeg -i "concat:./audios/تجربة-chunk0.mp3|./audios/تجربة-chunk1.mp3" -acodec copy ./audios/تجربة.mp3'
}
Chunk 1 created successfully
Chunk 0 created successfully

I expected the command to work in the nodejs app like in the command line